# Auto Scroll is not working in viewport in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have to allow scrolling in the view port items. I tried the below code. But its not working.

```
         var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
               layout   :'column',
               applyTo  : 'divPanel',
                items   : [{
                    title: 'title',
                    collapsible: true,
                    autoScoll: true,
                    columnWidth: .57,
                    items: [grid],
                    width: 300
                },{
                    columnWidth: .01,
                },{
                    columnWidth: .42,
                    autoScoll: true,
                    collapsible: true,
                    items:[Panel],
                    width: 250
                }]
         });
```

Any help is must appreciated..thankz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a scroll, you must define a height on the components that are inside the ViewPort.